# PowerShell script fails to retrieve information about installed updates from WSUS

Tags: windows, powershell

Scripts are being run from the WSUS server.

I want to check if selected KBs got installed on computers under WSUS, but the below script is always showing me that there are no updates installed at all:

```
# Set the WSUS server name
$wsusServer = "WSUS"
$wsusPort = 8530  # Specify the WSUS server port number

# Set the KB numbers to check
$kbNumbers = @("5026362", "5026363") # Add or modify the KB numbers as needed

# Connect to the WSUS server
$wsus = Get-WsusServer -Name $wsusServer -PortNumber $wsusPort

# Get all computers
$computers = $wsus.GetComputerTargets()

# Iterate over the computers
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Write-Host "Checking updates on computer $($computer.FullDomainName)"
    
    # Get the updates for the specified KB number installed on the computer
    $updates = $wsus.GetUpdates() | Where-Object { $_.Title -like "*$kbNumber*" } |
               Where-Object { $_.InstallationState -eq "Installed" -or $_.InstallationState -eq "InstalledPendingReboot" } |
               Where-Object { $_.ComputerTargetId -eq $computer.ComputerTargetId }

    # Check if the KB is installed on the computer
    if ($updates) {
        Write-Host "KB $($kbNumber) is installed on $($computer.FullDomainName)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "KB $($kbNumber) is not installed on $($computer.FullDomainName)"
    }
}
```

I have already tried a few modifications, but I'm almost always getting some errors like this one below:

`Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.UpdateServer] does not contain a method named 'GetUpdateInstallationInfoPerComputerTarget'.`

`Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.UpdateSummary] does not contain a method named 'GetUpdateInstallationInfoPerUpdate'.`

`Cannot find an overload for "GetSummariesPerComputerTarget" and the argument count: "1"`